# Tree collection of enums

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture

I'd like to put some data in a collection. I already have a solution, but I'd like to make it more generic and less ugly. IMHO nested dict's don't help much.

```
private static Dictionary<enumRoot, Dictionary<enumLevel1, Dictionary<enumLevel2, Tuple<int, bool, string>>>>
```

So each node/level should have a key, represented by an enum. At the end (a tuple ATM) should be some object. I thought about implementing some kind of recursive approach like a composite pattern. I thought about construct the object with a List or List and then add each.

I googled a TreeNodeCollection, but I couldn't find much informations about it. Does this collection work for my case and how can I project this problem?

Comment: I know it looks like a XML structure but its data depends from a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your node-based structure by relying on a custom `Class`. Example:

```
public enum nodeName { nodeName1, nodeName2, nodeName3 };
public enum nodeAttribute { nodeAttribute1, nodeAttribute2, nodeAttribute3 };
public class Node
{
    public nodeName name { get; set; }
    public Node parent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<nodeAttribute, string> attributes { get; set; }
    public List<Node> children { get; set; }
}
```

This can be easily populated with something like:

```
Node node1 = new Node();
Node node2 = new Node();

node1.name = nodeName.nodeName1;
node1.parent = null;
node1.attributes = new Dictionary<nodeAttribute, string>();
node1.attributes.Add(nodeAttribute.nodeAttribute1, "1");
node1.attributes.Add(nodeAttribute.nodeAttribute2, "2");
node1.children = new List<Node>();
node1.children.Add(node2);
```